# How to check is the given <ipfs_hash> is already fully downloaded or not?

Tags: ipfs

First when I run `ipfs --offline block stat <ipfs_hash>` and if the hash does not locally exist I get following message: `Error: blockservice: key not found`.

- Afterwards I run following: `ipfs object stat <ipfs_hash>` and after getting a valid output
- I run `ipfs --offline block stat <ipfs_hash>` again , now it always return valid information (hence does not give an error) even the hash is not downloaded.  So assuming if  `ipfs --offline block stat <ipfs_hash>` gives and `Error` message is not correlated that the given hash is locally downloaded.

How can I resolve this in order to detect if the asked hashed is fully downloaded or not?

---

I can do something like `ipfs refs local | grep <hash>` , but I don't want to keep fetch all the hashes and it will be slower when there is hundreds of hashes exist.

Related: https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/how-to-check-is-the-given-ipfs-hash-and-its-linked-hashes-already-downloaded-or-not/7588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ipfs files stat --with-local --size <path>` returns the downloaded percentage of the requested ipfs hash. If its `100.00%` than we can verify that its fully downloaded into local ipfs repo.

> ````
> ipfs files stat <path> - Display file status.
>
> --with-local  bool   - Compute the amount of the dag that is local, and if possible the total size.
> --size        bool   - Print only size. Implies '--format=<cumulsize>'. Conflicts with other format options. ```
> ````

---

```
$ hash="QmPHTrNR9yQYRU4Me4nSG5giZVxb4zTtEe1aZshgByFCFS"
$ ipfs files stat --with-local --size /ipfs/$hash
407624015
Local: 408 MB of 408 MB (100.00%)
```